# Handling form submittion

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I have a form within modal and I don't seem to be able to catch the submit event.

Let's say we have a html page defined as (for the sake of simplicity leaving out any templates defined by me)

```
<body>
    <button class="ui button">Open modal</button>
    <div class="ui small modal">
        <div class="header">
            Enter your email
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <form class="ui form">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="at icon"></i>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui error message">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui negative button">
                Cancel
            </div>
            <div class="ui positive primary loadable button">
                Reset password
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and registred template events

```
Template.body.events({
    'click button': function () {
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    },
    'submit form': function () {
        alert('called');
    }
});
```

When I submit the form it doesn't get cought by the handler. Why and what's the best approach?

I got something similar working by defining the inner content of modal as template, but it makes things much harder. Is there any other way?

**EDIT:** Here's [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/oToZSra8BEY2S8FZZ/Leaderboard) that demostrates the issue

Comment: How do you submit the form if there is no submit button in the form?

Comment: pressing enter in the field

Comment: so just add <input type="submit"> to form and it should work for you.

Comment: @MatiK see my comment Pawel's answer

Comment: Could you provide meteorpad.com with your code?

Comment: http://meteorpad.com/pad/oToZSra8BEY2S8FZZ/Leaderboard

Comment: this may be too obvious but are you `event.preventDefault`ing the form submit to keep the page from reloading?

Comment: @pikausp It looks it is a problem with semantic-ui. If you remove `modal` class from div all events are working properly.

Comment: Adding events i onRendered method with jquery works in your case: http://meteorpad.com/pad/iMdbkBv5tiZBXx62u/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

Comment: Curious if there's a way around it. It makes the code much less readable and consistent, thanks for the workaround. @DanielBeck the problem is not the default action, the problem is that the handler never gets executed

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was on the wrong track, wondering if you weren't seeing the event because the page was busy being reloaded. My bad

Comment: Alert is blocking function, the page wouldn't reload until confirmed

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this behavior is that modal is detached from the DOM. This behavior can be overriden by setting `detachable: false`

Here's working [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/tnGifn9o8caGPHxXB/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard%20(1))

[Credits](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/0Upkyo9F54k)